PyQT5 QtSerialPort problem reading Hex from port
I have the follow configuration:
Raspberry Rpi4B / Python 3.11.2 / PyQt5 5.15.9 Touch panel HDMI IPS 10,1" 1024x600
I have a problem when I use QtSerialPort for communicate with example a computer.
Opening communication is no problem, sending Hex data is no problem. Only when receiving Hex data it is
wrong end separate. See my my code below. I have tried different ways to read, always the same result.
I think I might not be using the correct command. It must be simple. I check the sending hex data with another computer it is correct.
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSerialPort

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.send1_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            text="Send1",
            clicked=self.send1
        )
        self.send2_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            text="Send2",
            clicked=self.send2
        )
        self.send3_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            text="Send3",
            clicked=self.send3
        )

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(self.send1_btn)
        hlay.addWidget(self.send2_btn)
        hlay.addWidget(self.send3_btn)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        
        self.serial = QtSerialPort.QSerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudRate=QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Baud57600,
        parity=QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.NoParity,
        dataBits=QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data8,
        stopBits=QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.OneStop)
        self.serial.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        self.serial.setDataTerminalReady(True)
        #self.serial.readyRead.connect(self.readFromSerial) 
        self.serial.readyRead.connect(self.handle_ready_Read)         

    #def readFromSerial(self):
    #self.Esp1=(self.serial.readLine().data())
        
    QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_ready_Read(self):
        self.Esp1 = self.serial.readAll()
        print (self.Esp1) 
        if (self.Esp1 ==b'xAAxO2x3Cx31x19   '): # Ok = xAAxO2x3Cx31x19        
                print ("Ok")
        else:
                print ("Error")
                                    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def send1(self):    
        # Reset,out service 
        self.serial.write(b'\xCC\x02\x3C\x55\x5F')
        # Syncro
        self.serial.write(b'\xCC\x02\x3C\x24\x2E')
        # Setup 
        self.serial.write(b'\xCC\x04\x3C\x23\x00\x10\x3F')
        # Enable
        self.serial.write(b'\xCC\x02\x3C\x12\x1C')
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def send2(self):
        # value  
        self.serial.write(b'\xCC\x04\x3C\x34\x00\x05\x45')
        self.step1=1
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def send3(self):
        # Confirm Ok 
        self.serial.write(b'\xCC\x02\x3C\x22\x2C')    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Output:
b'\xaa\x02'
Error
b'<1\x19'
Error

Hex data send xAAxO2x3Cx31x19
I tried different ways to read all give the same result
I recieve the follow
b'\xaa\x02'
b'<1\x19'

The correct data is:
b'xAAxO2x3Cx31x19


I have made some changes to the wording used. I hope I have correctly understood your question and my changes are correct. If not then please [edit] the question to correct it as necessary. (I do not have an answer to your question.)

Your solution is working perfect for me, without wrong messages. Great!
def handle_ready_Read(self):
    self.Esp1 = self.serial.readAll()
    while self.serial.waitForReadyRead(10):
        self.Esp1 += self.serial.readAll()
    if self.Esp1 ==b'\xaa\x02<1\x19': # Return Ok = xAAxO2x3Cx31x19
         self.Esp2=1
         print (self.Esp1,"Ok")
         self.serial.write(b'\xCC\x02\x3C\x22\x2C')  # Confirm Ok
    else:
         self.Esp2=2
         print (self.Esp1,"Error") # Error


The readout is correct. You have two issues here in your interpretation of it:

How the read data is represented
How the read data is divided into parts

If you look up the ASCII table, you will find that x3C is the character "<" and x31 is the character "1". When printing a binary string, it will print the characters for "printable" values, and only hex codes for "non-printable"/"control" values. Try print(self.Esp1.hex()) to see the hex numbers instead.
The other issue is that you are not receiving one telegram but two. This is why your comparison to the expected binary string fails. You need to collect the data until the expected number of bytes is received. You cannot count on all the data coming in at once.

When I change the print instruction the program stops. I  understand now that the print is in binary. Is it possible to give the correct read result so that I can compare the full hex message with b'xAAxO2x3Cx31x19 whether it is correct.

In handle_ready_Read, you need to loop over waitForReadyRead() until you received the number of bytes you expect or an expected stop character. You need to append all new bytes read within the loop. Finally you will be able to compare.
